# CSS and img dont read on Github

Tags: css, image, github

I'm trying to upload one project on github but CSS and img wont read. 
I have tried to upload it 2 times, and checked that files names is written with small letters and are the same in the name of the file and the same in the html code but it still wont work.
Site was build using bootstrap, it is first time for me using BS so i'm not sure if it is because of that.

I am attaching link to a site and link to my repositorie on github. are you able to see what problem is?

**Link to a site:**
https://veljko-premovic.github.io/Tindog/

**Link to repositorie:**
https://github.com/Veljko-Premovic/Tindog

thank you in advance
Veljko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are serving your images from a folder called images, but there is not such a folder.

The same with CSS, you are serving your styles.css from a “css” folder that is non-existent in your Github repo.

Either create those folders and add the images and CSS in them, or in every “src=“, remove the folder name.

Comment: It is working now. Thank you very much. 
I have changed name in HTML code and its working. 
Thank you one more time!

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck going forward with Angela Yu's course, it has also helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are wrong, they all point to `images/something.png` but the images are in the same root folder as index.html so it should just be

```
  <src img="something.png">
```

same for the css